# Node/Socket.IO sometimes not registering disconnect?

Tags: node.js, socket.io

Is there any possibility that sometimes Socket.IO does not register a disconnect? My server keeps a list of active players and does not allow anyone who is currently seen as "playing" by the server to load another instance of their game; however, sometimes, people will exit the page and try to load it up again and they'll get hit with a "this account is already playing" message.

This shouldn't happen as they are set inactive on disconnect. Is this event handler reliable? What could cause this to not be registered?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check the transport and make sure it uses websocket or flashsocket, as transports other than those two uses polling and relies on connection timeout to trigger the disconnect handler.